# how i can fix this problem? use of undeclared identifier 'flag'

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a,i,j;
    FILE *fp,*fw;
    fp=fopen("new.txt", "r");
    fw=fopen("exam.txt", "w");
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        int flag=0;
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&a);
        for(j=2;j<a;j++)
        {
            if(a%j==0){
                flag=1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==0){
        fprintf(fw,"%d number is prime \n",a);
    }
else
{
    fprintf(fw, "%d number is not prime \n",a);
}
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fw);
         }
```

ı want to print to file exam.txt whether the numbers in file new.txt are prime or not but when ı run the code it always writing 'number is not prime' .

Comment: Please search -> Block Scope: A Block is a set of statements enclosed within left and right braces i.e. '{' and '}' respectively

Comment: declare `flag` outside the loop. Or move the `if` inside it.

Comment: You should get an compiler error in your code `error: ‘flag’ undeclared (first use in this function)`. If not how are you compiling?

Comment: Your title says you get an error, “use of undeclared identifier 'flag'”, but your text says “when ı run the code…” You cannot run code for which the compiler reports an error, because the compiler does not produce an object module when there is an error. Are you running the program with different code than you show in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring flag inside the for loop. So it is not accessible outside the for loop. You need to declare it outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

A declaration, like `int flag=0;`, only makes an identifier known (available for use) within a region of the source code. That region is called the *scope* of the identifier. Within `int flag=0;` inside the compound statement formed by `{ … }`, its scope starts at the declaration and ends at the `}`.

Your `if(flag==0)` appears after that scope, so the identifier is not available for use at that point.

To make it available, move `int flag=0;` to earlier in the program, possibly just before the `for` statement.

The defined object also has a *lifetime*, which is the period of time during program execution that memory is reserved for it. Lifetimes are organized in classes called *storage durations*. An object defined inside a function without `static` or `extern` has *automatic storage duration*. For most objects with automatic storage duration, its lifetime begins when execution of its associated block starts and ends when execution of its associated block ends. If the object has a variable length array type, its lifetime starts when execution reaches its definition.